# Converting json data do google chart

Tags: php, json, graph

So I'm using `cURl` in **PHP**, to access a JSON Object and get the data from it. I am getting all the data, but I do not understand how can I draw a chart with this information.

Here is the **PHP Script:**

```
<?php
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, " https://xxx.xxx.pt/api/objgroupinfo/16Jcr05g37KpLklz");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "X-Apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, " https://xxx.xxxxx.pt/api/dataout/IAfhAfTIUZrCje5q.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "X-Apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-Startdate: 2016-10-01 00:00:00";
$headers[] = "X-Enddate: 2016-10-10 15:00:00";
$headers[] = "X-Channelnum: 0";
$headers[] = "X-Reclimit: 200";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: xxxx/1.0";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
$json = json_decode($result, true);
print_R($json);
echo "<h1> loll </h1>";
echo $json['location'];
echo "<br>";
echo $json['object_name'];
echo $json['channels'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($json['channels']); $i++) {
    echo $json['channels'][$i];
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I am getting something like this:

[image]

I already used j`son_decode` to transform the data into an PHP Array, but how can i used this data to build a graph with it?

Answer (score 0):

Demo is below ,let me know if any doubts.

You have to choose Anular JS for quicker implementation.

```
 <div>
 <div google-chart chart="chart" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}"/>
```

[***Demo***](https://plnkr.co/edit/N2Lvm70T1NUOig1zuvcz?p=preview)

Comment: but how to i put the data i pulled using cURL into the graph? I dont have a .json file, im using cURL to get the data

Comment: Just get the CURL PHP Response as JSON value and replace below part with your php filename

`return $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'xyz.php' })`